# RotateY in Chrome not working properly?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, css, rotation

I'm building a portfolio webpage for myself. I'm not a professional I do it because it is fun for me.

Here is my page: http://szifla.van.hu/keret.cgi?/23d/portfolio/index.html

If you open it in Firefox those pictures and text-boxes move and rotate them with css3 3d as I wanted. But it does not work in Chrome while it should because I added `-webkit-perspective` etc.

The problem might be in my script where i wrote

```
.style.transform = "rotateY(" + amount + "deg)";
```

I think this is not working, but I don't know how could I make it in another way:

```
.style.-webkit-transform = "rotateY(" + amount + "deg)";
```

Neither works in IE, but I don't care about that. First I want to make it work in FF,Chrome, Safari, Opera...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using jQuery for CSS3 transitions I recommend [Transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/), that way you'll avoid prefix hell.

Answer (score -1):

I see you already have jQuery on your site. Why not use it to rotate?

```
$('.d1').rotate(amount);
```

Comment: Can I rotate in 3d with that?